# How to serve content type for authorized users as for anonymous?

Tags: users, nodes, caching

I have content type "book". It's nodes are huge and it's takes a long time to format them by input filter. Caching works only for anonymous users.

So my goal is to give authorized users the cached version without APC, Cache Router (using a shared hosting).

I tried to change actual uid in template.php like so:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
    if (isset($vars['node']) && $vars['node']->type == 'book') {
        global $user;
        $user->uid = 0;
    }
}
```

But it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render the nodes with [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels), and you can set the caching across all users.

You could then either set it to a time based cache, or use my [Panels Cache](https://drupal.org/sandbox/Letharion/1663292) to get the cache cleared automatically when the nodes update.

See [Learn Page manager!](http://nodeone.se/sv/node/21) for an introduction to Panels and Page Manager.

Comment: Thanks, Letharion! You pointed me a new approach. I just used views, not panels. I created a block view (under content block) with the body field of node, set argument "nid" that is getting from url, hide body on the actual page and added "Views content cache" module to update block after node edit.

Comment: Glad you got it working. :)